# jquery each function does not work the way I want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I have following code:

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
  var items = val.items;
  console.log(val.id);
  if (val.id === this.id) {
    console.log('hello');
  }
});
```

In the above code, I am looping through `data` which is a JSON object. Then I compare the `id` of `val` with `this.id` which has value of `4`. Thus what I want is when `val.id (4)` equals to `this.id (4)` then log `hello`, however, since `data` has several objects so it logs several hellos.

Why and how can I make it so that it says hello only when it matches that condition and get out of that loop?

Comment: Inside `each` loop, `this` === `val`. Your initial `this` looses its value inside `.each`. So, just before the loop save `this.id` in a variable and compare that variable with `val.id` in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function defined within the call to `each()`, this === val.

If you're trying to compare to the value of `this.id` from before the call to each, you'll need to cache it, like so:

```
var someId = this.id;
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
  var items = val.items;
  console.log(val.id);
  if (val.id === someId) {
    console.log('hello');
  }
});
```

Comment: Now it doesn't even show hello only once. They are matching atleast once.

Comment: When I use two equals then it works but when I use three then it does not. Why?

Comment: @x4ph4r That would mean one of them is a NUMBER (4) and the other is TEXT a.k.a. STRING ("4"). They are considered equal when `==` (loose comparision) is used but not when `===` (strict comparison) is used.

Answer (score 0):

As Alison has said, `this` in side the function is `val` so you need some kind of caching. (This feature is useful when you only need the value but not the key, so you can have `function(){...}` and use `this` instead)

Also, if you want to break from the `.each` loop, return false inside the loop function:

```
var someId = this.id;
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    var items = val.items;
    console.log(val.id);
    if( val.id === someId ) {
        console.log('hello');
        return false;
    }
});
```

as specified in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: I did it that but now it doesn't even show hello once. But it does match values at least once.

Comment: What did you think is the `this` in the original code? `data`? Some other object?

Answer (score 0):

what you have here is, you are comparing the same data in if condition which is always true..
`this` represent to current element in each loop which in your case is `data` and same goes to `val` too.. you can try with `console.log(this)` inside the loop ..

```
if( val.id === this.id ){ //this will always be true
```

so you have to rethink your logic ..... what actually you need to match in the(that) condition.

> when it matches that condition and get out of that loop

try it out in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/fwPZn/)